# Appropriate way to implement a cli Application which also uses the service profile with Micronaut

Tags: java, micronaut, picocli

I've no problem in creating a REST Server or a Picocli CLI Application.
But what if I want to have both in one Application?

The thing is, I want to have an Application which provides some business logic via REST Server (no problem there), but in some other cases I want to trigger the business logic via CLI without starting the HTTP Server (eg. for CI/CD).

I'm not sure if I run into problems if I start the app via 
`PicocliRunner.run(Application.class, args)` and if a specific argument is given run the Server with `Micronaut.run(Application.class);`, since they create a different context.

Does anyone know a proper way to achieve this?

This is how I solved it:

```
import io.micronaut.configuration.picocli.PicocliRunner;
import io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut;
import picocli.CommandLine.Command;
import picocli.CommandLine.Parameters;

@Command(
        name = "RestAndCliExample",
        description = "...",
        mixinStandardHelpOptions = true
)
public class Application implements Runnable {
    private enum Mode {serve, run}

    @Parameters(index = "0", description = "Execution mode: ${COMPLETION-CANDIDATES}")
    private Mode mode;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        args = new String[]{"run"};
        PicocliRunner.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    public void run() {
        if (Mode.serve.equals(mode)) {
            // Start REST API
            Micronaut.run(Application.class);
        } else {
            // TODO run code directly
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to `@Inject` the `ApplicationContext` into your `@Command`-annotated class. This allows your command to use the same application context instead of needing to start a separate one.

Then, in your `run` method, you can start the REST server by obtaining the `EmbeddedServer` from the application context and calling `start` on it, or you can execute the functionality directly without the REST server.

See also this answer for more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56751733/1446916

Comment: Looks very promising but the server isn't running after calling server.start(). The application just exits. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Solved it now with a watcher Thread ... but this isn't the most elegant solution!
Isn't there a way that Micronaut can handle this on its own?

Comment: That’s a good question. Let’s try to get the Micronaut folks involved. I asked on the Micronaut Gitter channel.